# How to download the Log files from the tomcat server

Tags: java

i'm new in java.Can any one of you guide me how to download the log files from Tomcat Server ?? How Apache tomcat server is responsible for maintain log for java code??

Comment: <how to download the log files from Tomcat Server ??> you mean using java code?

Comment: yeah.Is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the log in tomcat server you can find it in your tomcat folder, but if you mean your log4j log, tomcat create a folder in your root drive that you put tomcat in.

Comment: i want to download a log file of log4j in java. Can you please help me regarding this ??

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you want, you can have the log as a file and you can read it as a file in java.